# How to enable GCP service Service Usage using a curl?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to enable service "Service Usage" in GCP project, so I could manage all the other services within that project, but to enable this project with a curl I need this project to be enabled beforehand. To me, this looks like a chicken-egg problem.

Comment: In order to use `curl` you will need to understand how to obtain OAuth Access Tokens and how to use the REST API. Unless you really like hard work, use a language like Python and supported libraries. On my website I have articles that will help you work with Google Cloud using `curl`, `python`, `PowerShell` etc. https://www.jhanley.com/

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, it would be easier and more straightforward to use the client libraries or even the Cloud SDK in order to administrate your services. Is there a reason you are unable to use these approaches and need to use cURL?